# Wrong keyboard when remote desktopping from windows to linux

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, fedora, kde

I installed xrdp on my Linux FC 17 KDE server, so that I can use mstsc from Windows to connect to it.

All works really well, except that I have a Swiss keyboard, and when I type say a Z, I get a Y on the screen (Swiss is QWERTZ and not QWERTY).

I installed Linux on the server while a Swiss keyboard was attached to it. Locally it works fine.

I tried adding a Swiss layout in the window called "Keyboard - KDE Control Module", but that doesn't help.

I use the same user, whether logging in locally or remotely.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Please log on to the server, open a terminal and post the output of this command: `echo $LANG`

Comment: en_US.UTF-8 - that's wrong!  What do I do now? :-)

Comment: @AntKutschera Buy a US keyboard? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

<del>Since you saw that the `$LANG` variable is wrong, you should try setting it in your `~/.bashrc`.</del>

Sorry, spoke too soon, and did not think. The $LANG variable controlls all aspects of your locale, not the keyboard layout as such. As far as I can tell, the easiest fix for this would be to add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
setxkbmap -layout de_CH
```

Now, I am not at all sure that is the correct name for the swiss layout you are using. I had a look around and [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KEYMAP) suggests either `de_CH` or `fr_CH`. However, neither works on my system but that might be just because I don't have the relevant layouts. Play around with `setxkbmap` just open a terminal and try out some layouts:

```
setxkbmap -layout de_CH
setxkbmap -layout fr_CH
```

etc etc.

You can have a look at some locale names at `/usr/share/i18n/locales/`, maybe you can identify the one you need :).

Comment: doesnt work :-(  I set it, reboot, logged in remotely, checked the LANG variable which now reads de_CH.UTF-8 (Swiss German variant), but the keyboard is working the same as before :-(

Comment: All it did was to make my shell output german error messages :-)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, see my updated answer.

Comment: The setxkbmap doesnt work for me either.  I am getting a bit further with this: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=265100  The first part (creating the file and putting it under /etc/xrdp and then rebooting works, but there are quite a few differences between my thinkpad T410 keyboard and that one.  are there any graphical tools which I can use where I can click a key and see its code?

Comment: `setxkbmap` really should work... You just have to figure out the correct layout name. Have you tried a _german_ german layout, as opposed to a swiss one? This command gives me a QWERTZ kezboard: `setxkbmap -layout de`

Comment: I worked out tonight that using VNC, the setxkbmap works as soon as I type it.  But I am using xrdp and that works differently.  I need to do what is described in the link I posted a couple of comments ago.  But the problem is that only some of the keys start working better.  Stuff like curly braces, which I need for programming, are input using the "alt" keys, and they don't work at all.  Not even with vnc.